# How to add condition to pivot table showing part of or manipulated source data

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, pivot-table, calculated-columns

I have an Excel sheet that has headers customers, number of cases, missed targets. Missed target tells how many out of all the cases has been missing target time.
I would like to create a pivot table and a chart of it showing the ratio of the missed target cases divided by all the cases related to a customer, basically telling you which the most problematic customers are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [calculated field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculate-values-in-a-pivottable-report-HP010382405.aspx?CTT=1#_Toc254345829) which you will be able to use in your pivot table.

In the Pivot Table tools, you'll find an option called **Fields, Items, & Sets**. From there, choose **Calculated Field**. Give the field a name like "Ratio of Missed Target" and then enter the formula you require: `='missed targets' / 'number of cases'` Click **Add**.

[image: How it would look in Excel 2003 (the version I have access to at the moment)]

*This is how it would look in Excel 2003 (the version I have access to at the moment)*

Then you will be able to use this field in your Pivot Table just as any other field.

Comment: Thanks. Just got back years later. ;)